# I would like to create a field type "Time"

Tags: datetime

not within or as a date.
If I use a number field, I'm not able to display a colon instead of comma or decimal dot.

How would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [Time Field module](https://www.drupal.org/project/time_field) which provides a time field for you.

> TimeField for Drupal 8 solves displaying and submitting time and time-range for Drupal site.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. There are 3 things the module should think about.
It lacks of international timeformat.
There should be a Suffix for French German or other languages.
And the time format could be displayed in Manage display to get an instant view if it is correct. I will post this as a feature request on the module page
Lothar